# How to disable Firebase completely? warnings and errors shown in log

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I'm disabling analytics on my project deleting the .json file and deleting this from app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And also deleting all the push or analytics init calls.

Also, I'm adding this on manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true"/>
```

Even I deleted the two notifications services from the manifst (`MESSAGING_EVENT` and `INSTANCE_ID_EVENT`)

But after doing that, I'm getting this error warning every time I open a section:

```
02-26 13:05:15.687 10605-10605/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
02-26 13:05:20.574 10605-10743/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.mypackage.myapp
02-26 13:05:20.578 10605-10743/? E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
```

What more should I do to completely disable Firebase without removing the Gradle compile files?

Comment: keep this in your gradle file `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: if i keep it then the compilation crashes because it tryes to find the .json file

Comment: what you did is written here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#temporarily_disable_collection_1, maybe clean and rebuild

Answer (score 2):

you can disable the analytics using

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

or

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

Comment: don't remove the json file..open the firebase console redownload it...this will work if you want to disable the analytics

Comment: what? i want to disable it by code, not by console, i dont understand you

Comment: redownload the json file you deleted and add the dependency again..and then 
 write FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false); in your launcher activity

Comment: what? the json file does not exist, the app doesn't have firebase anymore

Comment: how can I redownload something which doesn't exists?

Comment: you can always download the latest json file from firebase console..without json file you can't use firebase services

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165827/discussion-between-harsh-agrawal-and-nullpointerexception).

Comment: try removing  <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />   and clean your project